# Showing Null pointer exception can you please help me check code below

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

**Test:**

```
package com.digitalmqc.automation.ff.projectstests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.digitalmqc.automation.ff.projectspages.loginpage;
import com.digitalmqc.automation.utils.LoginTypes;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class CbaLoginandhomepagetest 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    //WebElement w;
    @Test
    public void cbalogin() throws Exception
    {
    LoginTypes type=PageFactory.initElements(driver,LoginTypes.class );
    type.cbachromeLogin();
    loginpage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, loginpage.class);
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
    login.cbclogin("abc","abc@gmail.com","xyz");


    }

}
```

**Page:**

```
 /* 
 */
package com.digitalmqc.automation.ff.projectspages;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

/**
 * @author user
 *
 */
public class loginpage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public loginpage(WebDriver ldriver)
    {
        this.driver=ldriver;
    }
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='cbDomain']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement domain;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='cbUname']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='cbPwd']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='ssoForm']/p[2]/button")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement submit;
    @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using=".//*[@id='ssoForm']/p[3]/a")
    WebElement forgotpassword;

    public void cbclogin(String domain_name,String uname,String pass)
    {
        domain.sendKeys(domain_name);
        username.sendKeys(uname);
        password.sendKeys(pass);
        submit.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Without knowing what the null pointer exception is, it's not possible to say what the problem is. You need to edit the question to include the error information.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the `Webdriver driver` field anywhere in your **Test** class. So you're essentially passing nothing to the **Page** constructor.

Try this:
`driver = new FirefoxDriver();`